# Creating custom proj4 string from components

Tags: coordinate-system, geopandas, proj, rasterio, pyproj

I'm trying to work with NOAA's NDFD weather data, which are released as rasters in GRIB format. Specifically, I'm currently trying to get the pixels that intersect an arbitrary geometry.

Information about the [grid's projection is here](https://www.weather.gov/mdl/ndfd_srs), and an [example GRIB file is here](https://nomads.ncdc.noaa.gov/data/ndfd/201701/20170101/YEUZ98_KWBN_201701010519) (42MB).

When I load the file with `rasterio`, I see that the bounds are essentially 0-1377 in the `y` direction and 0-2145 in the `x` direction:

```py
import rasterio
r = rasterio.open('YEUZ98_KWBN_201701010519')
r.bounds
>>> BoundingBox(left=-0.5, bottom=1376.5, right=2144.5, top=-0.5)
```

When I take that same file and run `gdalsrsinfo` on it, I get a proj4 string:

```
> gdalsrsinfo YEUZ98_KWBN_201701010519 -o proj4

+proj=lcc +lat_0=25 +lon_0=265 +lat_1=25 +lat_2=25 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +R=6371200 +units=m +no_defs
```

However if I take an arbitrary point in the US, and try to project it to that projection, I get x and y values way outside the 0-1377, 0-2145 range I expect:

```py
import geopandas as gpd
import pyproj
from shapely.geometry import Point

proj_str = '+proj=lcc +lat_0=25 +lon_0=265 +lat_1=25 +lat_2=25 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +R=6371200 +units=m +no_defs'
crs = pyproj.CRS.from_proj4(proj_str)

point = Point(-122.4194, 37.7749)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[point], crs={'init': 'epsg:4326'})
gdf = gdf.to_crs(crs)
list(gdf.iloc[0].geometry.coords)

# [(-2456716.706510244, 1682088.477346224)]
```

I expected this code to reproject the WGS84 point to a point on the NDFD grid, but it doesn't. Why not?

Edit: output of `gdalinfo`:

```
> gdalinfo YEUZ98_KWBN_201701010519
Driver: GRIB/GRIdded Binary (.grb, .grb2)
Files: YEUZ98_KWBN_201701010519
Size is 2145, 1377
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS["unnamed",
    BASEGEOGCRS["Coordinate System imported from GRIB file",
        DATUM["unnamed",
            ELLIPSOID["Sphere",6371200,0,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                    ID["EPSG",9001]]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                ID["EPSG",9122]]]],
    CONVERSION["unnamed",
        METHOD["Lambert Conic Conformal (2SP)",
            ID["EPSG",9802]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of false origin",25,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8821]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of false origin",265,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8822]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of 1st standard parallel",25,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8823]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of 2nd standard parallel",25,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8824]],
        PARAMETER["Easting at false origin",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["Metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8826]],
        PARAMETER["Northing at false origin",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["Metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8827]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["easting",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["Metre",1]],
        AXIS["northing",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["Metre",1]]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
Origin = (-2764474.350731994025409,3232111.710792394354939)
Pixel Size = (2539.702999999999975,-2539.702999999999975)
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-2764474.351, 3232111.711) (130d 7'22.60"W, 49d56'49.26"N)
Lower Left  (-2764474.351, -265059.320) (121d33'48.72"W, 20d10'43.04"N)
Upper Right ( 2683188.584, 3232111.711) ( 60d51'57.95"W, 50d 6'46.52"N)
Lower Right ( 2683188.584, -265059.320) ( 69d11'54.73"W, 20d19' 6.40"N)
Center      (  -40642.883, 1483526.195) ( 95d27' 8.65"W, 38d13' 5.87"N)
```

Comment: "*the bounds are essentially 0-1377 in the y direction and 0-2145 in the x direction*". The example is 2145 columns x 1377 rows, so rasterio isn't picking up the georeferencing and is just giving you the pixel coordinates, not the georeferenced coordinates.  What is the output of `gdalinfo examplegrib`? `gdalinfo` tells me it is properly georeferenced.

Comment: Yeah, I was also confused by that, because I thought rasterio just wraps GDAL, but `gdalinfo` says it's georeferenced and rasterio doesn't? I've been searching for a way to manually pass a crs to rasterio when reading a file but haven't found it yet.

Comment: But regardless of the `rasterio` issue, (which might be [this issue](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/issues/1248)), there must exist some transformation that takes latitude and longitude WGS84 points and converts them to the grid defined by [these parameters](https://www.weather.gov/mdl/ndfd_srs), right?

Comment: Use `with rasterio.Env(), rasterio.read('YEUZ98_KWBN_201701010519') as r:`

Comment: And you could do your point coord reprojection in rasterio to https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/rasterio.warp.html#rasterio.warp.transform

Comment: I'm pretty sure even with `rasterio.Env()` it's not correct. For example:

`with rasterio.Env(), rasterio.open('YEUZ98_KWBN_201701010003') as r:
    print(r.xy(0, 0))`

should print the latitude and longitude coordinates of 0,0 in pixel coordinates, but it prints: (0.0, 1376.0)

Comment: So I'm wondering if the CRS saved in the GRIB file is wrong, which is why I framed the question as creating a proj4 string from parameters.

Comment: And an even better indication that it doesn't work with `rasterio.Env()`, is that `r.bounds()` still gives `BoundingBox(left=-0.5, bottom=-0.5, right=2144.5, top=1376.5)`

Comment: I get the same results as gdalinfo if I use rasterio.Env()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I expected this code to reproject the WGS84 point to a point on the NDFD grid, but it doesn't. Why not?

Your code *does* reproject the WGS84 point to a point on the NDFD grid.

Your problem is that rasterio is not picking up your GRIB file georeferencing and just returning the bounds as pixel coordinates from 0-ncols, 0-nrows (in fact your code should not work at all as there is no `rasterio.read` function, but I'll assume you meant `rasterio.open`).

```
with rasterio.open('YEUZ98_KWBN_201701010519') as r:

    print(r.bounds)
    # BoundingBox(left=-0.5, bottom=1376.5, right=2144.5, top=-0.5)           

    print(r.shape)
    # (1377, 2145)

    print(r.crs)
    # None
```

You need to ensure your `GDAL_DATA` environment is set correctly (either as an environment variable that is picked up implicitly or explicitly via `with rasterio.Env(GDAL_DATA='/path/to/gdal/data')`) and then wrap your call to `rasterio.open` with the `rasterio.Env()` context manager.

Then you can reproject your points to the NDFD grid (either using your shapely and geopandas method or various other ways including rasterio.warp.transform) and intersect your GRIB with your reprojected points.  For example:

```
import rasterio
from rasterio.warp import transform

with rasterio.Env(), rasterio.open('YEUZ98_KWBN_201701010519') as r:
## OR with rasterio.Env(GDAL_DATA='/path/to/gdal/data'), rasterio.open('YEUZ98_KWBN_201701010519') as r:

    lon_lats = [[-122.4194, 37.7749], [-122.5, 37.75]]
    xys = list(zip(*transform({'init': 'epsg:4326'}, r.crs, *zip(*lon_lats))))
    data = list(r.sample(xys))

    print(r.bounds)
    # >>> BoundingBox(left=-2764474.3507319884, bottom=-265059.3202076056, right=2683188.584268011, top=3232111.7107923944)

    print(xys)
    # >>> [(-2456716.706510244, 1682088.477346224), (-2464411.5901549244, 1680767.699278633)]

    print(data)
    # >>> [array([ 8.85      ,  8.35      ,  8.35      ,  7.7499939 ,  7.7499939 ,
    #          7.7499939 ,  7.7499939 ,  7.7499939 ,  7.2499939 ,  7.2499939 ,
    #          7.2499939 ,  8.35      ,  8.85      ,  9.9500061 , 10.55001221,
    #         11.15001831, 11.65001831, 11.65001831, 11.65001831, 10.55001221,
    #          9.4500061 ,  8.85      ,  8.85      ,  8.35      ,  7.7499939 ,
    #          7.7499939 ,  7.2499939 ,  7.2499939 ,  6.65001831,  6.65001831,
    #          6.65001831,  6.65001831,  6.15001831,  6.15001831,  6.15001831,
    #          7.2499939 ,  7.7499939 ,  9.4500061 ,  9.9500061 ,  8.85      ,
    #          8.35      ,  7.7499939 ,  7.2499939 ,  7.2499939 ,  8.35      ,
    #          9.9500061 , 10.55001221]),
    #  array([ 7.7499939 ,  7.2499939 ,  7.7499939 ,  7.2499939 ,  7.2499939 ,
    #          6.65001831,  6.65001831,  6.65001831,  6.15001831,  6.15001831,
    #          6.15001831,  7.7499939 ,  8.85      ,  9.4500061 , 10.55001221,
    #         11.15001831, 11.15001831, 11.15001831, 10.55001221,  9.4500061 ,
    #          8.35      ,  8.35      ,  7.7499939 ,  7.2499939 ,  7.2499939 ,
    #          6.65001831,  7.2499939 ,  6.65001831,  6.65001831,  6.15001831,
    #          6.15001831,  6.15001831,  5.55001221,  5.55001221,  5.55001221,
    #          6.65001831,  7.7499939 ,  9.9500061 ,  9.4500061 ,  7.7499939 ,
    #          6.65001831,  6.15001831,  6.15001831,  5.55001221,  8.35      ,
    #         10.55001221,  9.9500061 ])]
```

If you still can't get rasterio to read the georeferencing, wrap the GRIB in a VRT:

```
gdal_translate -of VRT YEUZ98_KWBN_201701010519 YEUZ98_KWBN_201701010519.vrt
```

And rasterio will pick up the georeferencing without the `Env` context manager:

```
with rasterio.open('YEUZ98_KWBN_201701010519.vrt') as r:

    print(r.crs.to_proj4())
    # >>> +proj=lcc +lat_1=25 +lat_2=25 +lat_0=25 +lon_0=265 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371200 +b=6371200 +units=m +no_defs=True

    print(r.bounds)
    # >>> BoundingBox(left=-2764474.3507319884, bottom=-265059.3202076056, right=2683188.584268011, top=3232111.7107923944)
```

Comment: Thanks! After a few more hours working with those last comments, I was able to figure it out. One thing that was confusing me was that even after using `rasterio.Env`, the projected units were in _meters_ and not in _cells_.

Comment: @KyleBarron, not sure what you mean. The units are supposed to be metres, not cells. There are functions in rasterio to convert pixel/cell coordinates to map/georeferenced coordinates and vice-versa if you need that? But the sample function handles that for you when extracting pixel data values.